# Как изменить размер флажка (CheckBox)?

Tags: delphi

Как в Делфи изменить размер флажка (CheckBox). Можно ли это сделать? Или какой компонент можно взять, чтоб самому изменять его размер, или как написать подобный компонент?

Основная идея - использование флажка для выделения зоны программы и работы над зоной.

Comment: А можно примитивное объяснение к вот этому "использование флажка для выделения зоны программы и работы над зоной"?

Comment: Никогда не сталкивался с необходимостью изменять размеры стандартных элементов управления, кои к этому не особо располагают=)

Comment: А почему именно флажок? Он ведь будучи растянутым будет выглядеть подозрительно.. уж лучше тогда просто кнопку.. она хоть не так страшно масштабируется..

Comment: Мне нужна не кнопка а именно флажок, таким образом чтоб пользователь видел отмеченую строчку!

Comment: Мне нужен растянутый флажок:
           1. Размеры флажка соответствовали рядостоящему Едиту
           2. Программа будет использоватся на Тачскрине

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь `TSpeedButton` с картинкой. Эта кнопка может быть "залипшей", т.е. оставаться нажатой. Поставьте ей в дизайнере свойств `GroupIndex > 0` и `AllowAllUp = True`. Один клик - кнопка осталась нажатой, второй клик - кнопка отжалась.
Можно поставить сразу нужную картинку (четыре картинки рядом в одной) и задать свойство `NumGlyphs = 4`, тогда картинка будет меняться сама.

[image: Пример картинки]

Comment: Нашел пример использования `NumGlyphs`: http://ci-builder.ru/Pr/Index16.htm

Comment: Вот пример формы с такой кнопкой https://www.dropbox.com/s/kehdvm19nxpe118/Unit1.7z?dl=0

Comment: Ссылка на дропбокс быстро устареет/пропадет. Предлагаю просто вставить картинку в пост. Имеющихся инструкций будет вполне достаточно.

Comment: Этот вопрос задан 4 года назад. Кому я тут отвечаю? =(

Comment: Я кстати про NumGlyphs не знал, а теперь знаю - вы мне помогли =) и еще как минимум 2 плюсанувшим (и еще 225 человекам в год которые зайдут посмотреть решение с гугла).

Answer (score 0):

Варианты таковы:

1. Попробуйте изменить размер шрифта у checkbox.
2. Используйте банальную картинку вместо checkbox - сделайте две картинки нужного размера, с крестиком внутри и без... И при клике меняйте картинку... :)

Comment: Вариант с картинкой более-менее подходит ну всеже нужно доработать.
Размеры шрифта - Зачем?.. Шрифт изменится, а флажок - нет. Я не использую текст Caption флажка.

Comment: Да, размер щрифта не поможет... 
В общем, не стоит в нестандартной ситуации использовать стандартный checkbox - есть много распространенных способов показать переключение состояния... Картинка, изменение фона и цвета, рамка и.т.д.
И на все можно сделать компонент или просто класс, или просто кусок кода - это уже Вам решать :)